# Does this construction yield a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ from a basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a basis $(X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_m)$ for $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $(Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n)$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$, do the $mn$ matrices $X_iY_j^t$ form a bsis for the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ of all $m \times n$ matrices?

My initial guess is yes based on experimenting with the bases $\left\{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)\right\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$, as well as a couple of other examples. I wouldn't think there would be a pathological example where this does not work.

To prove this, let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be an $m \times n$ matrix. Let $[A]_{i, j}$ be the $j$th entry in the $i$th row of $A$.

Now I'm not quite sure how to describe which matrices to choose in our potential basis based on the bases for $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ to form our linear combination.

Comment: It seems in this question that $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are row vectors, and that superscript $t$ means transpose.

Comment: That is correct. $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are row vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $^t$ represents transpose.

Answer (score 1):

By regarding the cardinal, it suffice to show it is free. Let $(\alpha_{i,j})$ such that $\sum_{i,j}\alpha_{i,j}X_iY_j^t=0$, then $\sum_iX_iZ_i^t=0$ where $Z_i=\sum_j\alpha_{i,j}Y_i$, as $(X_i)_i$ is free it is easy (gy regarding the coordinates of $Z_i$) to show that, for each $i$, $Z_i=0$, so for all $i$, $\sum_j\alpha_{i,j}Y_j=0$, then for all $i$ for all $j$ , $\alpha_{i,j}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, is true for the canonical bases $(e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_m)$, $(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n)$. Let be $P,Q$ inversible such that
$$X_i=Pe_i,\qquad Y_j=Qf_j$$
(dimensions of $P,Q$?)

Then
$$X_iY^t_j = Pe_i(Qf_j)^t = P(e_if_j^t)Q^t.$$
What can you say about the function $M\longmapsto PMQ^t$?